# WPF set Propertyname from ItemsSource in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to build a UserControl where I can bind a ItemsSource and display a Collection of Thumbnails of the Objects. To let it be as general as possible I want to accept IEnumerable without any typ and deliver the Image Propertyname to the usercontrol.

For this, I have added two DependencyPropertys (ItemsSource (`IEnumerable`), BitmapImagePath(`string`)).

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.ThumbnailListControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <styles:SharedResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataItem">
                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </styles:SharedResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataItem}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type userControls:ThumbnailListControl}},
                                            Path=ItemsSource}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I don't have any idea how to archive this with Binding to the property name "BitmapImagePath". A possible solution is to use reflection in code behind but I think thats not an *elegant* solution.

In the parent UserControl I wan't to include the `ThumbnailList` like 
`<ThumbnailListControl ItemsSource="MyItemsSource" BitmapImagePath="ThumbnailImage" />`

Answer (score 0):

First, give your custom UserControl a name: `x:Name="MyUserControl"`.
Then in your DataTemplate simply bind to its dependency-property:

```
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataItem">
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=BitmapImagePath}" />
</DataTemplate>
...
```

Answer taken from: [Binding UserControl to its own dependencyProperty doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955833/binding-usercontrol-to-its-own-dependencyproperty-doesnt-work)

Comment: The problem is not to bind the dependency property. In my ItemsSource there are multiple Objects with the property "ThumbnailImage". This Property should by used for the image source.

Comment: So I think using `<Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailImage}" />` should work fine. If not, you can try putting your DataTemplate directly into your ItemsControl, without extracting it to UserControl.Resources.